# Click will a) scroll to div, b) open said div and c) load html from another page into that div. How?

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, slide

I already have the "scroll to" and toggle functions in place:

```
$("a.view").click(function(){
    $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

And the scrolling is taken care of via [this](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/) handy little plugin.

Now how do I load some html from another page into this newly opened div called #content. I've tried a few things here and there but just can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty trivial using jQuery.

```
$('#content').load('path/file.html', function() {
   // done
});
```

You may also "partial" load data, for instance

```
$('#content').load('path/file.html #container', function() {
   // done
});
```

will only load the element with the id `#container' out of file.html.

Ref.: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: But I would like the content to load after I click the button. Would this still work in this instance?

Comment: @lorenzium: sure, you would just pull the `load()` method into your `click event handler`. Notice that `#content'` can be replaced with `$(this)` in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks jAndy - you're a champ! Got it to work after that last explanation. Cheers.